# Type mismatch error passing a string to a function from an array (in VBA)

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel

I have a code like this

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ArrayStrings()
    Dim T As String, myResult As String

    ArrayStrings = Array("String1", "String2", "String3", "String4", "String5", "StringN")
    T = "myString"

    myResult = myFunction(T, ArrayStrings(1))
End Sub

Function myFunction(Tx1 As String, Tx2 As String) As String
    'myCode
End Function
```

This get an error "type mismatch" on "ArrayStrings(1)"

I tryed different ways but the only working seems to be:

```
    myResult = myFunction(T, CStr(ArrayStrings(1)))
```

But it seems strange convert a string to a string ... isn't it?
Is there any other way?

Comment: Your casting an `Array` to a string, not a `String` to a string

Comment: You can assign the `array(1)` element to a `string` variable and pass that to the function, or declare `Tx2 As Variant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, converting a string to a string isn't glamourous...

Have you tried to use `ByVal`?

`Function myFunction(Tx1 As String, ByVal Tx2 As String) As String`

That should be enough

Comment: Nope default is `ByRef`  ;)
I have to admit I use ByVal a lot (like for every arguments^^), not sure if it can be bad but it is widely useful!

Answer (score 2):

Try casting your array as a variant and then pass that into the function.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim str As String

    arr = Array("1", "2", "3")
    str = "Hello, world!"

    MsgBox myFunction(str, arr)
End Sub

Function myFunction(str As String, arr As Variant) As String
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim strOutput As String

    For Each var In arr
        strOutput = strOutput & " " & var
    Next var

    myFunction = strOutput
End Function
```

Comment: why should I prefer to use `Function myFunction(str As String, arr As Variant) As String`>; why using Variant where I need a string?